# Seekbar progressDrawable is offset in some of the devices (mostly observed in tablets)

Tags: android, seekbar

I have an `AppCompatSeekBar` which has a `progressDrawable` and they use 9 - patch images internally for the filled and the non filled section of the seekbar. Everything seems to work fine in most of the phones. But when it comes to few tablets the seek track is offset towards the top.

The following is the screenshot of the seekbar in a phone and it's behaving exactly like how it should :

[image]

This is in a 10 inch tablet :

[image: As you can see the progress is offset towards the top]

You can observe the progressDrawable or the seek is offset to the top.

So regarding my code this is in my xml :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSeekBar
      android:id="@+id/sbAudioSeek"
      fontPath="fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf"
      android:layout_width="@dimen/seek_width"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginRight="10dp"              
      android:background="@android:color/transparent"
      android:max="255"
      android:paddingRight="3dp"
      android:progress="0"                               
      android:progressDrawable=
              "@drawable/seekbar_track_progress_notifier"
      android:splitTrack="false"                
      android:thumb="@drawable/icon_thumb_notifier" />
```

Now this is my `seekbar_track_progress_notifier.xml` which is my progressDrawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/icon_track" />

    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <scale
            android:drawable="@drawable/seek_track_selected"
            android:scaleWidth="100%" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Here `seek_track_selected` and `icon_track` are 9 patch images I am using for my seekbar. I am clueless since its working in few devices and not working in some of the tablets.

Comment: what is the type of `@drawable/seek_track_selected` ? Is it another xml drawable?

Comment: As I have already mentioned at the last they are 9 patch images. seek_track_selected is a set of 9 patch images for hdpi, mdpi and so on resolutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned, `seek_track_selected` is 9-patch png. 
I'm not sure all your png files are properly patched. 
My suggestion is, cross-check what is the display density of the device it works and the device it doesn't work. Then compare the patch marks of those to specific files. Maybe you missed out to patch to top portion one dpi specific png.

Not sure, it's a wild guess. ;-)

Comment: It was a problem with my 9 patch of the mdpi resource. This solved the issue. Thanks.